# Can anyone please write in english what exactly this code means : soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout")

Tags: web-scraping

I wan to undetand in english what does this code means exacty.

I have tried leanring codes from beautifulsoup i got the hint but i am not able to get confidence.

```
soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout")
```

code says find all the tags which is

... and something

Answer (score 2):

I'll translate

```
soup.find_all("p", class_="strikeout")
```

as:

```
find all <p> tags with class equals to strikeout ( <p class="strikeout"> )
```

You should search the documentation (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) to find out if the class search is strict or not, meaning it will match or not something like

```
<p class="strikeout foo">
```